# Match single word with case insensitive and possible spaces before and after

Tags: javascript, regex

In Angular 8 I need to validate if a string is equal to `yes` allowing:

1. Spaces, and only spaces, before and after.
2. Case insensitive so `Yes`, `YES`, ... would be allowed.

I tried the following regex [Regexr](https://regexr.com/51n9u):

```
^(?i)yes$
```

But I get an error:

```
(?i) is not allowed in Javascript
```

And I am not allowing spaces between and after.

Comment: Invalid syntax.  Regex options are passed after the sequence: `/^yes$/i`

Comment: It should be `/^\s*yes\s*$/i`, where did you learn about `(?i)` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are looking for is `/ *yes */i`.